# How to import a project file into a python package?

Tags: python

I’m currently working on a python package which I want to publish on pypi. Let’s assume it’s called package.py

Let’s assume the following project structure:

```
some_project/
main.py
content.py
```

The developer would import package.py into main.py. Package.py would then need to access content.py in order to function properly.

How can I write the import statement in package.py so that it looks for a file called content.py in the project folder that it was imported into and then imports content.py?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand you but you may look for this file tree.

- main.py
- some_project/

  - __init__.py
  - package.py
  - content.py

package.py:

```
from .content import things # if you need things from content
```

main.py:

```
from some_project import package, content # to import things from the library
```

Comment: I think we misunderstood each other. Package.py is the package I want to publish on pypi. The other .py files belong to another developer who decided to install my package via pip install in his environment. He then imports the package package.py into his main.py via an import statement. Package.py then needs to look for a script called content.py in his local project folder and import it into package.py. How can I write this import statement in package.py?